# IF, OR and AND - Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I want to add I conditional column which:

- In the first and second step check only the code
- In the thrird step should check the code and the quantity

As soon as i add the third step it seems that all rules break up. Below is my code:

`= Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Category", each  if [#"Code"] = "1" or [#"Code"] = "2" then "Step 1"  else if  [#"Code"] = "3" then "Step 2"  else if [#"Code"] = "4"  or [#"Code"] = "5" and [Quantity] >0 then "Step 3_A"  else if [#"Code"] = "4"  or [#"Code"] = "5" and [Quantity] <0 then "Step 3_B"`

Any help?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @davidebacci I have update the code in the quetion.  The isue is the step 3 part. Something is wrong with the `AND` part because all the transaction with the specifi codes regardless the value of the quantity is flag as Step 3_A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parentheses.

[image]

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each if [#"Code"] = "1" or [#"Code"] = "2" then "Step 1"  else if  [#"Code"] = "3" then "Step 2"  else if ([#"Code"] = "4" and [Quantity] >0)  or ([#"Code"] = "5" and [Quantity] >0) then "Step 3_A"  else if ([#"Code"] = "4" and [Quantity] <0 ) or ([#"Code"] = "5" and [Quantity] <0) then "Step 3_B" else null)
```